# Changes in iOS PayPal SDK

Tags: ios, ios7, paypal

i´m struggling with the latest PayPal SDK!

They changed the whole library, so i can´t find how i can set a destination where the Payment should go.

```
PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = 
    [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithClientId:PayPayClientID
                                             receiverEmail:Payto
                                                   payerId:customerId
                                                   payment:payment
                                                  delegate:self];
```

In the example is the old style and i could set in the "Payto" variable the destination PayPal address. This is now not possible. I searched in the example App from PayPal and can`t find anything! 
Have someone of you the same problem or how can i solve it?

Than you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I feel your Pain. I've tried to convert from the PayPalMPL (Mobile Payments Library) to the new library twice, and both times got stymied by features which were in the MPL which haven't made it into the new library yet.

"Chained" and "Parallel" payments are two of these. So if you're attempting to do one of these, you'll have to go back to the MPL.

If you're not, then I think the answer is "You don't" (or get) to specify the PayTo, since the customer will "provide" that when they fill out the PayPal form.

Does that help?

Comment: Please go through this link it will help you. https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how that will help _me_. In any case, that link is just the link to the new IOS libraries, which I discussed.

Comment: @MichaelWilson Thank you! I expected something like that! All the work for nothing!